# Как запустить .jar с неизвестным названием из кода?

Tags: java, файлы, классы, jar

### Мне нужно запустить именно тот .jar который содержит определённые классы.

Например, в некой папле содержится 2 jar файла с любыми именами

Файл x:

Содержит класс *"Hello"*

Файл y:

Содержит класс *"Privet"*

**Нужный мне код должен запускать** '*любое имя.jar*' **с классом** '*Privet.class*'

Comment: C jar файлом можно работать как с zip архивом. Смотрите содержимое всех файлов, пока не найдете нужный и запускайте его.

Comment: Что значит "запустить"? Вызывать метод `main` в классе `Hello`?